# manipulating boxplot aesthetics in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am stuck on some details with boxplot. I am using the following data (well, this is a sample of it):

```
dput(birds[1:20,])
structure(list(status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), length = c(1520L, 
1250L, 870L, 720L, 820L, 770L, 50L, 570L, 580L, 480L, 470L, 450L, 
435L, 275L, 256L, 230L, 330L, 330L, 300L, 180L), mass = c(9600, 
5000, 3360, 2517, 3170, 4390, 1930, 1020, 910, 590, 539, 940, 
684, 230, 162, 170, 501, 439, 386, 95), range = c(1.21, 0.56, 
0.07, 1.1, 3.45, 2.96, 0.01, 9.01, 7.9, 4.33, 1.04, 2.17, 4.81, 
0.31, 0.24, 0.77, 2.23, 0.22, 2.4, 0.69), migr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), insect = c(12L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 12L), diet = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L)), .Names = c("status", "length", "mass", "range", "migr", 
"insect", "diet"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L
), class = "data.frame")
```

and have created plot like this one:

```
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))
}

plot2 <- ggplot(birds, aes(x = factor(diet, labels = c("herbivorous", "omnivorous","carnivorous")),
                           y = range, fill = factor(status,labels = c("absent", "present")))) + 
          geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Diet", fill = "Status") +
          stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text") +
          geom_jitter()
plot2
```

[image: ggplot]

Here is where i am stuck:

- I want the jitter plot to use different colors depending what `migr` is (Note: migr is 1-sedentary, 2- sedentary & migratory, 3 - migratory), ideally there would be a legend too. I have tried adding `+ geom_jitter(birds, aes (x = factor(diet))` -> unsucessfull.
- How can I shift the numbers (number of observations) to the middle of the boxplot. I tried different variation of `position`, but also with no luck.

Comment: Can you add what `give.n` is? I can have an answer for you but I need example data to see if the positioning works

Comment: @pdil sorry! seems that I have forgotten a pieco fo code - I have added it to the original question now. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing the factor levels outside the `ggplot` function:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- birds
df$diet <- factor(df$diet, levels = 1:3, labels = c("herbivorous", "omnivorous","carnivorous"))
df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = 0:1, labels = c("absent", "present"))
df$migr <- factor(df$migr, levels = 1:3, labels = c('sedentary', 'sedentary & migratory', 'migratory'))

give.n <- function(x){
    return(c(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = diet, y = range, fill = status)) +
    geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Diet", fill = "Status") +
    stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text",
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(color = migr)) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

As we have numbers and jitter set at the same time, it would be nice if the points in each box corresponds to the number. Therefore, we have to tell `geom_jitter` to jitter by status:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = diet, y = range, fill = status)) +
    geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Diet", fill = "Status") +
    stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text",
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(color = migr, group = status),
                position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.75)) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

If you want to change jitter width, change argument `jitter.width`of `position_jitterdodge`.

Comment: this work like a charm, thanks ! There is one more thing, the outliers get dispalayed in black. How can i make them be dispeyed in the respective color (and idealy add a label to it, to know which observation is the outlier)?

Comment: Are you using a different dataset?